# Jquery function call for animDropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
     function initSlideDrop(){
jQuery('#nav').animDropdown({
    hoverClass:'hover',
    dropClass:'drop-active',
    items: 'li',
    drop: '.drop',
    delay: 100,
    animSpeed: 300,
    effect: 'slide'
})
}
;(function($){
$.fn.animDropdown = function(o){
    // default options
    var options = $.extend({
        hoverClass:'hover',
        dropClass:'drop-active',
        items: '>li',
        drop: '>ul',
        delay: 100,
        animSpeed: 300,
        effect: 'fade'
    },o);
    ...
}}(jQuery));
```

This is the code in one of my jquery.js. When I am trying to call the initSlideDrop() method, it gets the `.aniDropDown()` block gets executed. But the `$.fn.animDropdown = function(o)` is not getting called. Can anyone please help on this ?